# php7-fpm ERROR: failed to retrieve TCP_INFO for socket: Protocol not available (92)

Tags: php, docker, caddy

I'm using abisoft/caddy-php docker image to run a basic php site. On all the images I'm building using this my /var/log/php7 file every millisecond writes

`ERROR: failed to retrieve TCP_INFO for socket: Protocol not available (92)`

When I connect via socket these errors go away. Everything works fine even though this error is being thrown. If it's a false error, how can I keep it out of my log files?

Caddyfile

```
my.domain.com

root /srv/public
gzip

fastcgi / 127.0.0.1:9000 php {
    root /srv/public
    index index.php
}

rewrite {
r .*
    ext /
    to /index.php?{query}
}

startup php-fpm7

log ./storage/logs/caddy-access.log
errors ./storage/logs/caddy-error.log
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM abiosoft/caddy:php
COPY Caddyfile /etc/Caddyfile
COPY app/ /srv
```

Comment: Show us your settings, docker file and docker-compose

Comment: @Rider_BY Docker-compose isn't necessary to reproduce the issue. I'm not sure but I think it's more of an OS / Caddy / Go issue possibly.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, running docker on WIndows Subsystem for Linux? If yes, you're likely affected by these: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/393 https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1982 - In short, WSL doesn't implement the TCP_INFO option of getsockopt(2)

Comment: I saw those issues too @Peping. I'm not running it in this fashion. Running with 17.06.2-ce-mac27 (19124).

Comment: @michael According to this file in a source code of an arbitrary github repo (grain of salt, please), OSX doesn't implement the TCP_INFO option either. https://github.com/esnet/iperf/blob/master/src/tcp_info.c . It looks like by running docker on linux, you tricked php-fpm into thinking it was running on a linux machine. Not too sure how to help you further though.

Answer (score 1):

Because your system does not support `TCP_INFO`, you can rebuild php by source code.
find source `main/php_config.h` and modify

> -- #define HAVE_LQ_TCP_INFO 1 
>   ++ //#define HAVE_LQ_TCP_INFO 1

```
make && make install
```